# execute command on ssh portforwading

Tags: linux, openssh

I have a user that is only allowed to open a ssh connection for a port forwarding.
Example from the .ssh/authorized_keys:

```
no-pty,no-X11-forwarding,permitopen="localhost:1237",command="/bin/echo INTERACTIVE SHELL NOT SUPPORTED" ssh-rsa AAAA ...
```

Is there a way to execute a script as soon as this user opens the port forwarding? If the user would login with ssh I could use a .bashrc file or something like that. But in this case no shell is executed.

regards
frafu